# c TCP socket connection refused for localhost

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, localhost, client-server

I'm trying to make a client/server program in localhost but the client can not connect to the server and I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

I have tried to debug the program and all the parameters seem to be ok.The server does bind, connect, listen and accept.

With the client code a get `connect: Invalid argument` error. Client (I'm calling the client from the console with `./client localhost`):

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int cd;
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in s_ain;
    unsigned char byte;

    hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    bzero((char *)&s_ain, sizeof(s_ain));
    s_ain.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&(s_ain.sin_addr),  hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    s_ain.sin_port = htons(1025);

    cd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if( connect(cd, (struct sockaddr*) &s_ain, sizeof(s_ain) == -1) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "connect: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }       

    printf("%s\n", "IT WORKS!");
    close(cd);
    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sd, cd;
    socklen_t size;     
    unsigned char byte;
    struct sockaddr_in s_ain, c_ain;    

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    bzero((char *)&s_ain, sizeof(s_ain));
    s_ain.sin_family = AF_INET;s_ain.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s_ain.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    s_ain.sin_port = htons(1025);

    if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_ain, sizeof(s_ain)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "err bind");
        return -1;
    }

    if(listen(sd, 5) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "err listen");
        return -1;
    }

    while(1) {
        size = sizeof(c_ain);
        cd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&c_ain, &size);
        printf("%s\n", "IT WORKS !");
    }
}
```

Comment: You *do* know that port numbers below 1024 are reserved and can't be used by non-privileged applications? Why don't you check for errors in the server application?

Comment: You also have *two* cases of *undefined behavior* in the server code, both related to the `size` variable? First of all the type is wrong, it should be a `socklen_t`. Secondly, it need to be *initialized* before calling `accept`, each time in the loop. See e.g. [this `accept` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html).

Comment: @JachimPleborg I have tried with 1025 with no luck either.

Comment: And by the way, when [`connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) fails, try printing out the value of [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see what error you actually get. You can use [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a printable string from the error code.

Comment: @JachimPleborg I have updated the server with `socklen_t` and what you said but still not working.

Comment: @JachimPleborg I get `connect: Invalid argument` error. The strange thing is that I have another program where I do basically the same and I get `connect: Connection refused`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you have a typo in your example, or

```
if( connect(cd, (struct sockaddr*) &s_ain, sizeof(s_ain) == -1) ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "err connect");
    return -1;
}
```

has wrong parenthesis. Currently you will call `connect` with `socklen_t addrlen` as `0`. It should read

```
if( connect(cd, (struct sockaddr*) &s_ain, sizeof(s_ain)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "err connect");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: ...and this Q&A goes into my 'debug failure - did not reduce compound expression into simpler lines with intermediate vars' bookmark list.

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes in server.c

```
#include <netinet/in.h> // fix
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sd, cd;
    unsigned char byte;
    struct sockaddr_in c_ain;

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    bzero((char *)&c_ain, sizeof(c_ain));
    c_ain.sin_family = AF_INET;
    c_ain.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    c_ain.sin_port = htons(1025);

    bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&c_ain, sizeof(c_ain));
    listen(sd, 5);

    struct sockaddr_in t_ain;
    while(1) {
       int size = sizeof(t_ain); // < fix
       cd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&t_ain, (socklen_t*)&size); // < fix
       printf("%s\n", "IT WORKS !");
    }
}
```

Also to test server you can use telnet:

> telnet 127.0.0.1 1025